# Next.js Deploy to Netlify

Tags: next.js, netlify

I am trying to deploy my Next.js app into Netlify using Github, the build succeeds, but when I open the page it says "page not found". Additionally, my repo consists of two files: *front_end* where my next.js repo lives and *back_end* where my solidity smart contract lives.

These are my build settings
[image: Build settings]

How can I ensure that the page is found?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer here with my problem by a user **kirillibrahim**:

https://answers.netlify.com/t/deployment-of-nextjs-website-page-not-found/28870/4

```
[build]
   command = "npm run build && npm run export"
   publish = "out"
```

**netlify.toml** at root folder

```
"scripts": {
   "export": "next export"
},
```

**package.json** at root folder

*Build settings* for the netlify project;

Build command: **npm run build && npm run export**

Publish directory: **out**

Comment: but this is for static export? What about SSR?

Comment: I think you just remove the npm run export